# Discordjs not sending messages

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

The bot turns online and has its status working. However, when i type commands in like "/ping" or "/beep" the bot does not message anything! I gave the bot admin permissions as well

```js
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
const prefix = "/";

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

client.once(Events.ClientReady, (c) => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
    client.user.setActivity("testing");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content === "/ping") {
        message.channel.send("Pong.");
    } else if (message.content.startsWith("/beep")) {
        message.channel.send("Boop.");
    }
});
// Log in to Discord with your client's token
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `GuildMessages` gateway intent which is required for receiving the `messageCreate` event.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages] });
```

Answer (score -1):

A few things wrong here.

## Intents

All Discord Clients (as of discord.js v13) require you to have intents enabled to receive designated events. In the provided code, you will need the following Intents:

- `GatewayIntentBits.Guilds`
- `GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages`
- `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` (this must be enabled on the Developer Portal!)

## Client Activity

In the latest versions of discord.js (presuming you're on discord.js v14), you will need to change how your client activity is set.

```js
client.user.setActivity({
    activities: [
        {
            name: "testing",
            type: ActivityType.Playing,
        }
    ],

    status: "online",
});
```

Obviously, put that in your Ready event, and import ActivityType.

## Message Event

The Message Event has been deprecated since the release of discord.js v13.
Instead, use the "messageCreate" (`Events.MessageCreate`) event.

This is to better to work with the "interactionCreate" (`Events.InteractionCreate`) event for things like Slash Commands.

I also recommend switching your prefix to something like "!" or "?" because of Slash Commands.

Hope this helps!